# When using df.add() column ordering seems to change

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the `.add()` function to data from multiple dfs into a single summary df. They all share the same column naming but after the add when I look at the destination df the column ordering seems to be changed from the order when created to an alphabetic ascending order.

Is there some way to control that behavior or is the solution simply to, once the process completes and the summary df is updated to create a new df from that and specify the column order.

So if the produced summary df columns looked like `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` but the original order was `['C', 'A', 'D', 'B']` I would write:

```
new_df = sum_df[['C', 'A', 'D', 'B']]
```

Comment: Just write `new_df = sum_df[['C', 'A', 'D', 'B']]` or `new_df = sum_df[original_df.columns]`

Comment: Hello, could you please demonstratre this with a full [mre]?

Comment: From some quick tests, it looks like, if the columns are in the same order, it'll keep that order, but if they're not, it'll sort them.

Comment: @wjandrea - Interesting. I'll have to double check that. I actually create the summary df with a list for the column names. When reading the csv files I include the usecols= and provide the same list. As the answer indicates, maybe something to do with presence of NaN values -- which I don't drop until the end when I write the df to a file.  Might play a bit -- or just ignore the change or reorder manually with the columns list I already have. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any NaN values in your dataframe? I am thinking 'C' would have the first non NaN value, enabling `.add()` to perform its task in C first.

Either ways, this should keep the column order:

```
summary_df = pandas.Dataframe() # initiate an empty dataframe
summary_df['C'] = df1['C'] + df2['C']
summary_df['A'] = df1['A'] + df2['A']
summary_df['D'] = df1['D'] + df2['D']
summary_df['B'] = df1['B'] + df2['B']
```